# Angular app config crash after add second view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two different login views login.html and adminLogin.html so in Angular app.js I added first one as:

```
 $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: "/login.html",
                templateUrl: "../login.html",
                controller: "login",
                authenticate: false,
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                            name: 'myapp',
                            insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files

                        });
                    }]
                }
            })
```

and it runs correctly, problem is when I try to add second one below this one as:

```
.state('login', {
    url: "/adminLogin.html",
    templateUrl: "../adminLogin.html",
    controller: "adminLogin",
    authenticate: false,
    data: { pageTitle: 'INICIAR SESIÓN' },
    resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: 'myapp',
                insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before a LINK element with this ID. Dynamic CSS files must be loaded between core and theme css files

        }]
    }
})
```

When I try to acces first one or new one it only show blank page

> Note**: if I comment last code, first one runs correctly again.

Some one know what is wrong there? Help is very appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two states with the same name: `login`. The UI-Router has no idea what to do in that situation. Try re-naming your second state to something like `adminLogin`.

Comment: If you found this answer to be helpful, could you please upvote/set it as the selected answer? Thank you. :)